# Filling between two curves, according to a colormap given by a function MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fill

How can the area between two curves be filled by a colormap that fits the values of a function.

for example, here are the two curves, and the function of the values I would like to have in between

```
L=5;
x=1:10;
t=(1:10)/10;
figure(1)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,t,x+L,t)
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,exp(-(x/L).^2))
```

The filled area should be taken from any colormap.

[image]

Comment: You want the entire subplot 2 to fit between the lines, or just the corresponding `x` values?

Comment: so basically you don't want to fill an area between two lines, you want to plot a surface ?

Comment: @AnderBiguri, the entire subplot, the x values are shifted as t grows larger (subplot 1)

Comment: @obchardon. Yes, the colors though will represent the "z" coordinate (it will be a 2d plot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some basic indexing, rescaling of the gaussian length and line equation maths, we can do this by:

```
L=5;
x=1:10;
t=(1:10)/10;


[X,Y]=meshgrid(linspace(0,x(end)+L,500),linspace(0,t(end),500));

%slope of both lines
m=(t(2)-t(1))/(x(2)-x(1));

for ii=1:size(X,1)
z(ii,:)=exp(-((X(ii,:)-Y(ii,1)/m)/(L/2)).^2);
end


% basic line maths an dindexing
z(Y./X>m)=NaN;
z((Y+m*L)./X<m)=NaN;

surf(X,Y,z,'linestyle','none')
view(2)
```

[image]